# Jquery getting a child class of a selector retrieved using .prev

Tags: jquery

```
back = $("#contactus_"+id).prev();
```

I'm probably asking a simple question, but how do I get at .up_btn class from the id above?

normally to target this class i would do $("#contactus_"+id+" .up_btn") however in this instance I can't place the class name in there like that since I want the previous sibling's child.

Thanks

Comment: Is `.up_btn` a child of the previous sibling that you're trying to get? Because then you could just add `.find('.up_btn')` to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean `.up_btn` is found in that previous sibling,

```
$('#contactus_' + id).prev().find('.up_btn');
```

To use it with the `back` variable,

```
var back = $('#contactus_' + id).prev();
var btn = back.find('.up_btn');
```